# How to remove special characters from Pandas DF?

Tags: python, pandas, special-characters

I have a Python BOT that queries a database, saves the output to Pandas Dataframe and writes the data to an Excel template.

Yesterday the data did not saved to the Excel template because one of the fields in a record contain the following characters:

```
",  *,  /,  (, ), :,\n
```

Pandas failed to save the data to the file.

This is the code that creates the dataframe:

```
upload_df = sql_df.copy()
```

This code prepares the template file with time/date stamp

```
src = file_name.format(val="")
date_str = " " + str(datetime.today().strftime("%d%m%Y%H%M%S"))
dst_file = file_name.format(val=date_str)
copyfile(src, os.path.join(save_path, dst_file))
work_book = load_workbook(os.path.join(save_path, dst_file))
```

and this code saves the dataframe to the excel file

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(save_path, dst_file), engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = work_book
writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in work_book.worksheets}
upload_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow = 1, index=False, header = False)
writer.save()
```

My question is how can I clean the special characters from an specific column `[description]` in my dataframe before I write it to the Excel template?

I have tried:

```
upload_df['Name'] = upload_df['Name'].replace(to_replace= r'\W',value=' ',regex=True)
```

But this removes everything and not a certain type of special character.
I guess we could use a list of items and iterate through the list and run the *replace* but is there a more Pythonic solution ?

adding the data that corrupted the excel file and prevent pandas to write the information:

this is an example of the text that created the problem i changed a few normal characters to keep privacy but is the same data tha corrupted the file:

> """*** CRQ.: N/A  ***  DF2100109  SADSFO CADSFVO EN SERWO  JL1047 EL
> PUWERTDTO  EL DIA 08-09-2021  A LAS 11:00 HRS. PERA REALIZAR TRWEROS
> DE AWERWRTURA DE SITIO PARA MWERWO PWERRVO.
>
> - RWERE DE WERDDFF EN SITIO : ING. JWER ERR3WRR ERRSDFF   DFFF :RERFD      DDDDF : 33 315678905. 1) ADFDSF SDFDF Y DFDFF DE DFDF Y DFFF XXCVV Y
>   CXCVDDÓN DE DFFFD EN DFDFFDD 2) EN SDFF DE REQUERIRSE: SDFFDF Y SDFDFF
>   DE EEERRW HJGHJ (ACCESO, GHJHJ, GHJHJ, RRRTTEE Y ACCESO A LA YUYUGGG
>
> 3. RETIRAR JJGHJGHGH
>
> - CONSIDERACIONES FGFFDGFG:  SE FGGG LLAVE  DE FF LLEVAR FFDDF PARA ERTBGFY Y SOLDAR.""S:  SE GDFGDFG LLAVE  DE ERTFFFGG, FGGGFF EQUIPO
>   PARA DFGFGFGFG Y SOLDAR."""

Comment: See my edit with running result of your edited text sample.  See if this works for you from my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some of the special characters to remove are regex meta-characters, we have to ***escape*** these characters before we can replace them to empty strings with regex.

You can automate escaping these special character by [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape), as follows:

```
import re

# put the special characters in a list
special_char = ['"', '*', '/', '(', ')', ':', '\n']

special_char_escaped = list(map(re.escape, special_char))
```

The resultant list of escaped special characters is as follows:

```
print(special_char_escaped)

['"', '\\*', '/', '\\(', '\\)', ':', '\\\n']
```

Then, we can remove the special characters with [`.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) as follows:

```
upload_df['Name'] = upload_df['Name'].replace(special_char_escaped, '', regex=True)
```

**Demo**

**Data Setup**

```
upload_df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['"abc*/(xyz):\npqr']})

                Name
0  "abc*/(xyz):\npqr
```

**Run codes:**

```
import re

# put the special characters in a list
special_char = ['"', '*', '/', '(', ')', ':', '\n']

special_char_escaped = list(map(re.escape, special_char))

upload_df['Name'] = upload_df['Name'].replace(special_char_escaped, '', regex=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print(upload_df)


        Name
0  abcxyzpqr
```

### Edit

With your edited text sample, here is the result after removing the special characters:

```
print(upload_df)

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          Name
0                                                                                                           CRQ. NA  DF2100109 SADSFO CADSFVO EN SERWO JL1047 EL PUWERTDTO EL DIA 08-09-2021 A LAS 1100 HRS. PERA REALIZAR TRWEROS DE AWERWRTURA DE SITIO PARA MWERWO PWERRVO.
1  RWERE DE WERDDFF EN SITIO  ING. JWER ERR3WRR ERRSDFF DFFF RERFD DDDDF  33 315678905. 1 ADFDSF SDFDF Y DFDFF DE DFDF Y DFFF XXCVV Y CXCVDDÓN DE DFFFD EN DFDFFDD 2 EN SDFF DE REQUERIRSE SDFFDF Y SDFDFF DE EEERRW HJGHJ ACCESO, GHJHJ, GHJHJ, RRRTTEE Y ACCESO A LA YUYUGGG
2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         3. RETIRAR JJGHJGHGH
3                                                                                                                       CONSIDERACIONES FGFFDGFG SE FGGG LLAVE DE FF LLEVAR FFDDF PARA ERTBGFY Y SOLDAR.S SE GDFGDFG LLAVE DE ERTFFFGG, FGGGFF EQUIPO PARA DFGFGFGFG Y SOLDAR.
```

The special characters listed in your question have all been removed.  Please check whether it is ok now.

Comment: thank you this solution worekd for me also I found the special character that was causing the issue the UNIT SEPARATOR : 
001 1111 037 31 1F S7 US ␟ ^_  Unit Separator I address that to the list like this:   [\x00-\x1f\x7f-\x9f] and worked

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following (pass characters as a list to the method parameter):

```py
upload_df['Name'] = upload_df['Name'].replace(
    to_replace=['"', '*', '/', '()', ':', '\n'],
    value=' '
)
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason it still doesn't seem to work, i've copied the code exactly and tried to run it. Then I've tried to only apply it to the column it needs to be applied to: no luck.

Comment: @Greyfox are you sure you implemented it correctly? My answer is taken directly out of the [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas-dataframe-replace)...

Comment: I did and it does removed those special charcacters, but  pandas still has issues to save the data, I imagint there are other special charcarters that Im not seeing, I added here a copy of ther data that is corrupting the process

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.replace`:

```
>>> df
                Name
0  (**Hello\nWorld:)


>>> df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(r'''["*/():\\n]''', '', regex=True)
>>> df
         Name
0  HelloWorld
```

Maybe you want to replace line breaks by whitespaces:

```
>>> df = df.replace({'Name': {r'["*/():]': '',
                              r'\\n': ' '}}, regex=True)
>>> df
          Name
0  Hello World
```